# How to access the cerberus local development token using java code

Tags: java

Cerberus provides a local development token for access to it in local environment. I have currently hard-coded this value in my code. Is there a way to access this token using java code. Since it is hard-coded and it has got an expiry time, we have to keep changing the value every time it expires

Comment: How do you take the new token

Comment: The new token is available when i login to the Cerberus UI profile. They have provided a token for local development. I can view it in the application.

Comment: since you are taking the token on login then you can do it, How ?
do http request to that login form and get the token after login from the Http Response